# JPA entity without underlying table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a class that can be mapped to a result extracted from the database using JPA native query. Is there a way to map an entity without an underlying table to the result?
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002989/hibernate-entities-without-underlying-tables) link which allows it for hibernate. Can this be done using JPA instead?

This is my class for which I want the result to be mapped.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
public class OpUsage {  
    String username;    
    BigDecimal number_of_clicks;    
    String accordion;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public BigDecimal getNumber_of_clicks() {
        return number_of_clicks;
    }
    public void setNumber_of_clicks(BigDecimal number_of_clicks) {
        this.number_of_clicks = number_of_clicks;
    }

    public String getAccordion() {
        return accordion;
    }

    public void setAccordion(String accordion) {
        this.accordion = accordion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not mention that this object is to be used in Jasper reports. So i have to use the same name as used in the reports.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) defines the means to return the result from a native query to a non entity class

You should checkout the heading **3.10.16.2 Returning Unmanaged Instances** especially the

**3.10.16.2.2 Constructor Results**

> The mapping to constructors is specified using the *ConstructorResult*
>   annotation element of the *SqlResultSetMapping* annotation. The
>   *targetClass* element of the *ConstructorResult* annotation specifies the
>   class whose constructor corresponds to the specified columns. All
>   columns corresponding to arguments of the intended constructor must be
>   specified using the columns element of the *ConstructorResult*
>   annotation in the same order as that of the argument list of the
>   constructor. Any entities returned as constructor results will be in
>   either the new or the detached state, depending on whether a primary
>   key is retrieved for the constructed object.

**example**

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS
        avgOrder" +
        "FROM Customer c, Orders o " +
                "WHERE o.cid = c.id " +
                "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
        "CustomerDetailsResult");

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CustomerDetailsResult",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "orderCount"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "avgOrder", type = Double.class)})
        })
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. Only have to make sure to add the SqlResultSetMapping in a class that is annotated with @Entity and not in the non-entity class or Spring will not recognize the mapping.

Comment: Can you please provide the detailed example?
This does give me what I am looking for but what I am unable to understand is, where do we put the above code ? in repository layer or the bean itself?

Comment: A hint for placement can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636004/where-to-place-sqlresultsetmapping-in-case-of-constructorresult