# JPA support for Table Partition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

We have a use case where we need to create a table for month wise data. Example, we want to maintain order month wise. So Table names may be Order_Jan_17, Order_Jab_18. As the fields are same in each table and also tables names are dynamic. Can we have an Entity class Order without table name and in JPA query, get dynamic table name depending upon date rang and map result to Order Entity. Does JPA have support for this kind of use case?

Comment: No you cannot. No it doesnt

Comment: Ohh.. Then if its not straightforward support, will try with work around support like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945146/jpa-entity-without-underlying-table.Thanks