# hibernate hql sum case when then else end execution in java problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, createquery

I need to execute a `HQL query` with sum when then else end clause in *Java* that run with no problem in `postgres` :

```
SELECT r.reviewer_id,
  sum(case when c.service_type = 'مالتی مدیا' AND c.genre_id = '66c92962-324c-11e7-93ae-92361f002671' then 1 else 0 end) image_multimedia,
  sum(case when c.service_type is null AND c.genre_id = '66c92b1a-324c-11e7-93ae-92361f002671' then 1 else 0 end) image_null

 FROM module_samim.content c
  Join module_samim.content_reviewer r on c.id = r.content_id
  Join module_samim.file f on f.id = c.file_id
  Group by r.reviewer_id
```

I tried to run it with `createQuery()` but I get :

```
Sep 11, 2018 8:57:20 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:58: expecting "then", found 'مدیاAND'
line 1:58: expecting "then", found 'مدیاAND'
and

Sep 11, 2018 8:57:20 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:264: unexpected token: image_null
Sep 11, 2018 8:57:20 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:264: unexpected token: image_null
line 1:264: unexpected token: image_null
```

please help me!
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)) 
I used `createNativeQuery()` and @SqlResultSetMapping explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945146/jpa-entity-without-underlying-table) to solve my problem completely

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be a SQL, not HQL.

Therefore, we need instead of this

```
createQuery()
```

to call that

```
createSqlQuery()
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not return list() and with getSingleResult() return nothing, it even does not show an error! just jump to final

Comment: To get more understanding how to use HQL, do read this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html. And if you would really still need raw SQL, this should help https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html (there would be need to use some transformers, converting result columns into entity)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mixing the usage of native query over HQL/JPQL createQuery API

Just to clarify it for you, there are three different ways we can create a SQL query in Hibernate:

```
   1) session.createQuery()             //Hibernate APi
   2) entityManager.createQuery()       //JPA Api

   3) session.createSQLQuery()          // **** Hibernate API ****
   4) entityManager.createNativeQuery() //JPA API
```

> - So if you are using Hibernate, you should user  session.createSQLQuery()  and if you are using JPA you should use entityManager.createNativeQuery()

Comment: mapping error not related to this question, it means you succeeded in your problem with the current question and now have issue with your mapping entity configuration

Comment: session.createSQLQuery() deosnot response any way.