# Not able to inject DTO into spring repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where I have to use the DTO to get the required details from the table (let's say employee) the table is having number of columns but need to get only few columns I want create DTO with required number of columns from employee table and will get the distinct employee DOB from the employee table using DTO with JPA, I have created a DTO class and mapping it with repository but facing issue "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0".
I am using Native query to get the distinct empdob from employee but looks like something is wrong with the way constructor called from query.

Employee DTO :-

```
public class EmpInfoDTO {
    
    private String empDob;
    
    public EmpInfoDTO(String empDob) {
        this.empDob = empDob;
    }

    /*** @return the empDob */
    public String getEmpDob() {
        return empDob;
    }

    /*** @param empDob the empDob to set*/
    public void setEmpDob(String empDob) {
        this.empDob = empDob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmpInfoDTO" 
                + "empDob='" + getEmpDob() + "'"
                + "}";
    }
```

Repository :-

```
import com.domain.EmpInfoDTO;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface EmpInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<EmpInfoDTO, String>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT new com.domain.EmpInfoDTO(emp.empDob) FROM Employee emp"
            + "WHERE emp.empDob BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-60,'yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') ORDER BY emp.empDob DESC", nativeQuery = true)   
    List < EmpInfoDTO > findDistinctEmpDob();
}
```

Resource :-

```
import com.domain.EmpInfoDTO;
import com.repository.EmpInfoRepository;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Emp")
public class EmpInfoResource {
    
    private final EmpInfoRepository empInfoRepository;
    
    public EmpInfoResource(EmpInfoRepository empInfoRepository) {
        this.empInfoRepository = empInfoRepository;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/EmpDate/")
    @Timed
    public List<EmpInfoDTO> getDistinctEmpDob() {           
        List<EmpInfoDTO> empDateList = null;        
        empDateList = empInfoRepository.findDistinctEmpDob();            
        return empDateList;       
    }
}
```

I have debug all the possibilities but still unable to figure out what going wrong here..

StackTrace :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empInfoResource' defined in file [..rest\EmpInfoResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empInfoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.domain.EmpInfoDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empInfoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.domain.EmpInfoDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.domain.EmpInfoDTO
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:188) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:123) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Comment: not a managed type might be a hint, that you should have to annotate your entity (not the DTO!) with @Entity.

Comment: I have to use it as DTO hence not add annotations on DTO class

Answer (score 0):

You can create Spring Data JPA repositories only for managed types. In order for the rest of the code to work you `EmpInfoDTO`  needs an `@Entity` annotation to make it a managed type.

Alternatively, and probably better you can add `List < EmpInfoDTO > findDistinctEmpDob()` to the `EmployeeRepository` which I assume exists for the entity `Employee`

Comment: Thanks Jens for the reply, if you can see my repository I have already added List < EmpInfoDTO > findDistinctEmpDob() in repository.

Comment: Yeah, but in a repository that can't possibly work. As long as `EmpInfoDTO` isn't an entity.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it by following [JPA entity without underlying table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945146/jpa-entity-without-underlying-table) with this link need to add few mappings and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only think you need to change is the first paramter to Employee.

```
// @Repository THIS CAN BE REMOVED
public interface EmpInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String>{
```

Btw. Interfaces that extend JpaRepository don't need an annotation

Comment: I am not able to understand what this Employee represent here, you mean to say I need to send table name here  public interface EmpInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String>{

Comment: You must have an Entity class Employee, right? Otherwise the constructor expression query will not work at all

Comment: got it Simon and I am able to fix it.